# ERROR: Failed building wheel for httptools

Tags: python, installation, anaconda, rasa-nlu

```
while trying to install rasa nlu i am getting following error:

 Building wheel for httptools (setup.py) ... error
 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: 'e:\anaconda\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, 
 tokenize; sys.argv[0] = 
'"'"'C:\\Users\\sajjan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install- 
s8m8v74o\\httptools\\setup.py'"'"'; 
__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\sajjan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install- 
s8m8v74o\\httptools\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', 
open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', 
'"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' 
bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\sajjan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-ghmdzsv5' -- 
python-tag cp37
     cwd: C:\Users\sajjan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install- 
s8m8v74o\httptools\
Complete output (21 lines):
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\httptools
copying httptools\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\httptools
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\httptools\parser
copying httptools\parser\errors.py -> build\lib.win-amd64- 
3.7\httptools\parser
  copying httptools\parser\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64- 
3.7\httptools\parser
 running egg_info
 writing httptools.egg-info\PKG-INFO
 writing dependency_links to httptools.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
 writing top-level names to httptools.egg-info\top_level.txt
 reading manifest file 'httptools.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
 reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
 writing manifest file 'httptools.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
 copying httptools\parser\parser.c -> build\lib.win-amd64- 
 3.7\httptools\parser
 running build_ext
 building 'httptools.parser.parser' extension
 error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft 
 Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    ----------------------------------------
   ERROR: Failed building wheel for httptools
   Running setup.py clean for httptools
   Failed to build httptools
   Installing collected packages: httptools, sanic, colorclass, kafka- 
 python, async-generator, jmespath, botocore, s3transfer, boto3, sanic- 
 plugins-framework, sanic-cors, pydot, python-telegram-bot, python- 
 engineio, python-socketio, twilio, jsonpickle, fbmessenger, 
 terminaltables, docopt, pykwalify, humanfriendly, coloredlogs, python- 
 crfsuite, tabulate, sklearn-crfsuite, redis, fakeredis, tensorboard, 
 tensorflow-estimator, tensorflow, requests-toolbelt, webexteamssdk, 
 colorhash, ConfigArgParse, flask-cors, rasa-sdk, mattermostwrapper, 
 ruamel.yaml, pymongo, rocketchat-API, websocket-client, slackclient, 
 rasa, rasa-x
 Running setup.py install for httptools ... error
 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
  command: 'e:\anaconda\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, 
 tokenize; sys.argv[0] = 
 '"'"'C:\\Users\\sajjan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install- 
 s8m8v74o\\httptools\\setup.py'"'"'; 
 __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\sajjan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install- 
 s8m8v74o\\httptools\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', 
 open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', 
 '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' 
 install --record 'C:\Users\sajjan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record- 
 vut086we\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed -- 
compile --user --prefix=
     cwd: C:\Users\sajjan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install- 
 s8m8v74o\httptools\
 Complete output (21 lines):
 running install
 running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\httptools
copying httptools\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\httptools
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\httptools\parser
copying httptools\parser\errors.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\httptools\parser
copying httptools\parser\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\httptools\parser
running egg_info
writing httptools.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to httptools.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to httptools.egg-info\top_level.txt
reading manifest file 'httptools.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
writing manifest file 'httptools.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
copying httptools\parser\parser.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\httptools\parser
running build_ext
building 'httptools.parser.parser' extension
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'e:\anaconda\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\sajjan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-s8m8v74o\httptools\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\sajjan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-s8m8v74o\httptools\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\sajjan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record- 
    vut086we\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile -- 
    user --prefix= Check the logs for full command output.

Comment: It tells you that the library has compiled code, but you do not have compilers. Easiest solution for you is probably `conda install -c conda-forge httptools`

Comment: @cel thank you man, it worked, after a week's struggle i finally installed rasa, you are my messiah

Comment: You have not specified which windows OS version you are using. But the error is quite self explanatory. You need to install Microsoft VC++ build tools 14.0 version.

Answer (score 2):

Try with this command on your anaconda prompt and try again for install rasa. I think this will solve your problem

```
conda install -c conda-forge httptools
```

Comment: I don't know what `conda ` is. Is this something related to python?

Comment: Anaconda (or conda in the CLI) is a separate package registry, like PyPI for python. And the `-c conda-forge` tells it to look for a valid package in THAT registry instead of the default python one.

Answer (score 2):

Working solution I found for similar problem,

Go to [Visual Studio download page](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/) as mentioned in the error, download the installer for the latest version, run the installer,

if you already installed visual studio then click modify,
make sure to select the required packages, especially 'windows 10 sdk' as in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfTMI.png) [Around 1.2gb download and 4.2gb disk space needed for first install].

Then run  `pip install rasa_nlu`, to successfully build the package.

If Anaconda distribution is installed in your system, you can try running

```
conda install -c conda-forge httptools
```

then try to run the pip command,

But it won't work for all windows-python version combinations.Any time, building these kind of package requires visual c++.